Who moved my squash seeds?
I planted 3 hills each of zucchini, delicata, and butternut squash in the garden.  When the seeds came up, there were several plants growing at least 6-10 feet from where I planted them.  The garden is fenced off.
Who would move the seeds?  They seem too large to be moved by the wind.
There is a 5' fence around the garden, which keeps out large animals.  If it matters, I live in northeast US, zone 5.

Sorry, that was me

Birds, squirrels, voles, etc.
Takes a flawless fence (with a top and bottom, not just sides, and very fine mesh, and no gaps) to keep those out.

Could also be groundhogs, depending where you live! Our groundhog has a special affinity for my bean seeds/seedlings.

Next year you can take measures to protect the seeds before they emerge. A thick layer of cayenne pepper powder in my seedling pots worked well for me! Once the plants emerge the danger has passed.
